People wake up in a warehouse after memories have been erased?
I'm trying to identify a low budget english or american movie made sometime in the last two decades.
The parts I can remember involve a group of people waking up in a warehouse or factory without any memories of why they are there. Their memories were erased as the side effect of the release of some gas.
Most of the action takes place in the single warehouse-like location.
The movie involves them trying to remember who they are and why they were in the warehouse. The theme involved questions such as: Were they good guys or bad guys? Is this a heist or crime gone wrong? Is anyone else coming to the location and what are they going to do if that happens?
The movie was some sort of crime/thriller with psychological threads.
The movie didn't (at least in my memory of it) have any major stars.

It could be Unknown (2010).

Unknown is a 2006 American mystery thriller film directed by Colombian filmmaker Simon Brand and starring Jim Caviezel, Greg Kinnear, Bridget Moynahan, Joe Pantoliano and Barry Pepper about a group of men kidnapped and locked in a factory with no memory of how they arrived there.
Piecing together information around them, they realize that some were kidnapped and some were the kidnappers. They decide they must work together to figure out how to get away before the gang that captured them returns.

The stars are mostly B-list, not major stars.  It also wasn't a major film.
Unknown on IMDB.

Sounds right. I'll look it up and see.

That was it. More complex that I remembered and more known stars in the cast (though not big stars when made).
